# using innerHTML in a loop is not properly displaying the set of json results

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using an HTML onclick event to call a function that will read a Javascript string containing JSON syntax and output the results, but only the last result is being shown.

```
var resorts = '{ "skiResorts" : [' +
    '{ "resortName":"Afton Alps" , "resortState":"Minnesota" },' +
    '{ "resortName":"Alpine Way" , "resortState":"Pennsylvania" },' +
    '{ "resortName":"Alyeska" , "resortState":"Alaska" } ]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(resorts);

function displaySkiResorts() {
    //code
    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById("req8").innerHTML = obj.skiResorts[i].resortName + " " + obj.skiResorts[i].resortState;
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this show the entire set of ski resorts?

Comment: why not use an object literal?

Comment: You need to provide more information; are there errors? Is it just printing out the wrong values?

Comment: `obj.length == undefined`.

Comment: Your `obj` is an object, not an array. So use `obj.skiResorts.length`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error. You must itterate over obj.skiResorts but not obj
So the result code would be

```
var resorts = '{ "skiResorts" : [' +
         '{ "resortName":"Afton Alps" , "resortState":"Minnesota" },' +
         '{ "resortName":"Alpine Way" , "resortState":"Pennsylvania" },' +
         '{ "resortName":"Alyeska" , "resortState":"Alaska" } ]}';

      var obj = JSON.parse(resorts);

      function displaySkiResorts() {
        //code
        for (i = 0; i < obj.skiResorts.length; i++) {
          document.getElementById("req8").innerHTML += obj.skiResorts[i].resortName + " " + obj.skiResorts[i].resortState + "<br />";
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the right acces to the array length `obj.skiResorts.length`, change the assignment to `+=` and add a line break `<br>`.

```js
var resorts = '{ "skiResorts" : [' +
         '{ "resortName":"Afton Alps" , "resortState":"Minnesota" },' +
         '{ "resortName":"Alpine Way" , "resortState":"Pennsylvania" },' +
         '{ "resortName":"Alyeska" , "resortState":"Alaska" } ]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(resorts);
function displaySkiResorts() {
    for (i = 0; i < obj.skiResorts.length; i++) { // obj.skiResorts.length right array
        document.getElementById("req8").innerHTML += obj.skiResorts[i].resortName + " " + obj.skiResorts[i].resortState + '<br>'; // += and <br> 
    }
}
displaySkiResorts();
```

```html
<div id="req8"></div>
```

Comment: Nina thank you, thank you!!!!  The += was the key that I was missing (after so many helpful people pointed out that I needed to specify obj.skiResorts!!!).  I am so JSON phobic that I literally go tharn like a Watership Down rabbit whenever I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

[Nina's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35233413/1391671) correctly points out both issues (that your loop condition is incorrect, and that you are overwriting the `innerHTML` of the output element on each iteration).

I wanted to point out an optimization. In the body of your loop, on each iteration, you

1. lookup an element by ID, and
2. modify its `innerHTML` which will cause the browser to re-render.

Both of these operations can be done once, outside the loop. Build-up the HTML you would like to insert into the output element, and do it in one operation, like so

```js
var resorts = '{ "skiResorts" : [' +
    '{ "resortName":"Afton Alps" , "resortState":"Minnesota" },' +
    '{ "resortName":"Alpine Way" , "resortState":"Pennsylvania" },' +
    '{ "resortName":"Alyeska" , "resortState":"Alaska" } ]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(resorts);

function displaySkiResorts() {
    // build array of lines of HTML
    var length = obj.skiResorts.length;
    var html = new Array(length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        html[i] = obj.skiResorts[i].resortName + " " + obj.skiResorts[i].resortState
    }

    // insert into output, separated by line breaks
    document.getElementById('req8').innerHTML = html.join('<br>');
}
displaySkiResorts();
```

```html
<div id="req8"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (i = 0; i < obj.skiResorts.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById("req8").innerHTML= obj.skiResorts[i].resortName + " " + obj.skiResorts[i].resortState;
}
```

As @putvande points out, you are overwriting the same element each time. It's not clear what you were trying to do there. Did you mean to concatenate them?

Comment: Maybe another thing to mention is that the innerHTML gets overwritten.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: I know it's getting closed anyway, may as well help the guy.

Comment: @MattBurland: If you know it's getting closed then you _shouldn't_ answer. You can't just answer anyway, worse while throwing our quality limits out the window. That people answer off-topic questions is _why_ people keep asking them!!! http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133552/155739

Comment: Why would it get closed? OP still has yet to get a valid solution to his question.

Comment: @william.taylor.09: Closure is not about whether an answer was provided. It is about the quality of the question, and this question is lacking in an MCVE. Indeed, the problem statement as it currently stands is "it doesn't".

Comment: @william.taylor.09: No problemo :D)

Comment: @PreferenceBean - It lacks a minimal example? I certainly shows an attempt to display a result from from in an html element. Perhaps you should review the closure reasons a little closer.

Comment: @TravisJ: I am extremely familiar with the closure reasons. Review my profile. Then re-read my previous comment. There is no problem statement and the "minimal example" is not complete. For example _"I'm using an HTML onclick event"_ but the event is not shown. The problem could be anywhere. The question is off-topic. Feel free to use your edit powers to help the OP clean it up.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: It's far from a perfect question, but it's has code and they state it doesn't work. I think you are being far too trigger happy here.

Comment: @PreferenceBean - Yes, I see your meta activity. I looked before I commented. It is actually very surprising to see you even discuss a meta issue in a comment thread like this since that is generally seen by the crowd at meta as inappropriate. And yet, here we are. There is a problem statement. The user has json. They parsed it. They attempted to iterate over it to display. It broke. They showed their attempt. It was recreateable. The *title* may be in need of changing, but the overall post is not in need of closure. Editing should take priority. You should know this.

Comment: I just tried using obj.skiResorts.length and have some joy BUT it only outputs the last key:value pair in the array...

Comment: @MattBurland: Yes, stating "it doesn't work" is _not enough_. That is the point. I extend my invitation for Travis to improve the post, now to you.

Comment: @TravisJ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. It is not complete as it doesn't even contain some of the code mentioned in the prose. And "it doesn't work" is not verifiable. My final comment on the matter.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Also their code as they posted it *doesn't actually give an error message* so I'm not sure what else you think they should put in there. If they knew what the problem was, they wouldn't be asking the question. If there's any reason to close, it's probably a typo because the error is quite trivial. They said what they *expected it to do* and that it *didn't do anything*.

Comment: @PreferenceBean - Thank you for agreeing with me. Minimal, complete, verifyable. It is not off topic.

Comment: For what it is worth, I tried to get the html onclick code ( <button onclick = "displaySkiResorts()">Display Ski Resorts</button>) but could not get it to render here correctly when I copied it in

Comment: I see this sparked a whole discussion on whether this question is an ok one or formatted ok or....I think the bigger question is, is this a forum that is open and welcoming to those that are new to coding and/or new to Stackoverflow and how to best school those that are new here.  I certainly did not mean to violate any written or unwritten rules with my post (I will certainly try to find the MCVE (?) and see if I can figure out how my post violated it!) but I can say that I most heartily appreciate those who stepped in to help with my coding dilemma. This forum is so wonderful for newbies.

Comment: @Travis-J thank you so much for editing and re-stating the issue I had in a more globally useful, informative and accessible way!!!